# Call a method in AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() when creating a login in Facebook with React Native

Tags: javascript, facebook, react-native, authentication

In my app I'm creating a login in Facebook with React Native, and this my code:

```
 async handleFacebookLogin() {
    LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile', 'email', 'user_friends']).then(
        function (result) {
            if (result.isCancelled) {
                console.log('Login cancelled')
            } else {
                console.log('Login success with permissions: ' + result.grantedPermissions.toString())

                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
                    async (data) => {

                        let resultChild = await loginWithFaceBook(data.accessToken.toString(), "POST");

                        if (resultChild.username.length > 0) {
                            this.loginWithFaceBook(resultChild.token);
                        }
                    });
            }
        },
        function (error) {
            console.log('Login fail with error: ' + error)
        }
    )
}
```

My method:

```
loginWithFaceBook = async (tokenFace) => {
    Toast.show('Login success!');
    this.saveTokenLogin(tokenFace); 
}
```

This my error:

```
_this.loginWithFaceBook is not a function
```

How to use a method in `AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert this code:

```
const _this = this;
```

to below code:

```
async handleFacebookLogin() {
```

and replace this code:

```
  this.loginWithFaceBook(resultChild.token);
```

by to this code:

```
_this.loginWithFaceBook(resultChild.token);
```

Enjoy.

this is full code:

```
 async handleFacebookLogin() {
    const _this = this;
    LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile', 'email']).then(
        function (result) {
            if (result.isCancelled) {
                console.log('Login cancelled')
            } else {
                console.log('Login success with permissions: ' + result.grantedPermissions.toString())
                let tokenFace = '';
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
                    async (data) => {
                        data.accessToken)
                        let resultChild = await loginWithFaceBook(data.accessToken.toString(), "POST");
                        if (resultChild.username.length > 0) {
                            _this.loginFaceBook(resultChild.token);
                        }
                    });
            }
        },
        function (error) {
            console.log('Login fail with error: ' + error)
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: can you pls let me know where should i wright const _this = this;??